# Consular report of birth abroad or birth certificate

Tags: united-kingdom, us-citizens

My son was born in the UK, but we have immigrated back to the US. Does the US consular report of birth abroad form substitute for a birth certificate, or is there a reason to have a copy of his UK birth certificate. If the UK birth certificate is needed, do we need the long or short version?

Comment: For what purposes?

Comment: @MichaelHampton for any purpose that he is likely to encounter in his lifetime.

Comment: I just did a little searching and for everything I could think of where one might use a birth certificate, consular report of birth abroad was also acceptable.

Comment: I just thought of a context in which the US consular report of birth abroad is not as useful as a UK birth certificate: in dealings with the UK government. If your son is a British citizen, for example, it may be necessary to show the birth certificate when appying for a passport.  Another context where the birth certificate would probably be preferable would be dealings with any other government.  They're more likely to want a British birth certificate than a US CRBA.

Comment: The CRBA and birth certificate are different things. The former proves US citizenship at birth. The latter proves the details of birth without regards to nationality or immigration status. Both are needed, for different things.

Comment: @user102008 but for US purposes, and indeed for any country with strict jus soli, the birth certificate serves as proof of citizenship (even if it shouldn't because there is a small minority of people born in the US who don't acquire US citizenship).  Similarly, the CRBA shows the city and date of birth and lists the parents' names and dates of birth.  For US purposes, then, a CRBA has essentially the same function as a US birth certificate, even if the documents are legally distinct.